# How do I call a function defined in C++ object from a python program?

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I have a C++ program:

```
class X
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        int func(char *str);
};
```

Now I want to call the function func in my Python program. How can I do it?

I have successfully called C functions from my Python program using ctypes. 
However I can't seem to figure out how to call functions defined inside C++ objects.

I have already worked with ctypes, so I would like to figure out how to accomplishing it that way. However I'm open to other techniques. Also my project puts a constarint that I am not supposed to use wrapper function in my C++ program.

Comment: Who thinks this is "not a real question"? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question ctypes, but you cannot instantiate a C++ object directly from ctypes. You can wrap the C++ object in a C interface and then use ctypes. Or you could write a Python extension module which could include C++ code.

Comment: You mean to say i first need to study writing python extension module(I am not supposed to use wrapper functions) to accomplish my task..

Comment: Your question says nothing about these extra constraints you are adding in comments. Please can you correct the question.

Comment: I have edited my question to include my constraint. Now, can you advice me on how to move forward.

Comment: Your options are 1. Wrap the C++ code in a C style wrapper. 2. Write an extension module. SWIG and Boost.Python both make it easier for you to create an extension module.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`Boost::Python`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/).

Comment: thank you friend.. but I am not supposed to write wraaper functions which i will need to write in boost Python..

Comment: "supposed to"? Isn't it your project?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Boost.Python is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Answer (score 0):

try http://swig.org/
years ago i wrapped some c/c++ code to use them in wxPython with swig.
i cannot remember too much details but i think swig is easy to use.

Hope that helps.